# What can I use to replace Compass and create semantic markup in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, compass-sass

Prior to Rails 3.1 I used [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) to build clean semantic markup.  Compass is not yet ready for Rails 3.1 and it somehow feels too heavy and a forced fit with the new asset pipeline.  What other options are there for achieving beautiful, clean semantic markup in Rails projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a good solution, so I created one:

https://github.com/gavinhughes/semantic_grid